# OTRS CSS/js not loading when using with mod_auth_cas and login through API and CAS ticket

Tags: php, cas, otrs

Team,
I have created SSO using CAS, php application and OTRS

I am getting logged in into php application through CAS server using CAS apis.
From index.php php application code:

```
$ckfile = tempnam("/tmp", "CURLCOOKIE");
$useragent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36';
/**
 * Get __VIEWSTATE & __EVENTVALIDATION
 */
$ch = curl_init(CAS_URL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $ckfile);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent);
$html = curl_exec($ch);
$errorNo = curl_errno($ch);
$curlError = curl_error($ch);
curl_close($ch);
if ($errorNo == false) {
} else {
    return $return = array(
        'type' => 'error',
        'message' => 'Curl error: ' . $curlError . ' ' . $errorNo,
        'serviceURL' => '',
    );
}
$serviceValue = '';
$dom = new DOMDocument();
# Parse the HTML
# The @ before the method call suppresses any warnings that
# loadHTML might throw because of invalid HTML in the page.
@$dom->loadHTML($html);
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('form') as $input) {
    # Show the attribute value
    $serviceValue = $input->getAttribute('action');
}
```

now using this service value to get ST ticket

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $serviceValue);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "service=https://10.10.1.80/otrs");    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, );    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$ticket = curl_exec($ch);
$errorNo = curl_errno($ch);
$curlError = curl_error($ch);
curl_close($ch);
if ($errorNo == false) {
} else {
    return $return = array(
        'type' => 'error',
        'message' => 'Curl error: ' . $curlError . ' ' . $errorNo,
        'ticket' => '',
    );
}
```

Now I am using this ST ticket to hit otrs as

https://10.10.1.80/otrs/customer.pl?ticket=$ticket

I am able to successfully login into the OTRS but the UI gets distorted as otrs is unable to render following css and js file with URLs:

https://10.10.1.80/otrs-web/skins/Customer/default/css-cache/CommonCSS_102b06602eb972432ddd82f2c05c1b80.css

It is hitting CAS login call back url set on the httpd.conf file
But I logged into through the API not the application itself

I don't know how to resolve the issue

Please provide some work around

Thanks